# Pig, replace a string by an integer for a specifc column

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig, so this might be a trivial question. I could not get a reasonable answer hence asking this.

Have 3 columns as follows:

```
userid  itemid action
245      4     'view'
245      6     'click'
149      12     'buy'
149      1      'click'
```

and so on...

I have a mapping given such as : `'view'=1 , 'click'=1.4 , 'buy'= 2.1` etc.

My desired output is:

```
userid  itemid action
245      4       1
245      6      1.4
149      12     2.1
149      1      1.4
```

Simple commands that can help me achieve this?
I ll need to perform some cacluation on the 3rd column and hence can't have it in string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping file in HDFS with these mapping values, like:

```
action_string action_value
view 1
click 1.4
buy 2.1
```

Say this file is stored at `<mapping_file>`. Then just load this file and join your original dataset with this file:

```
mapping = LOAD '<mapping_file>' USING PigStorage() AS action_string, action_value;
joined = JOIN original BY action, mapping BY action_string USING 'replicated';
output = FOREACH joined GENERATE userid, itemid, action_value;
```

There are other ways depending on your use case and your file size. But I think this is the most flexible.